# Excel macro disabled warning not showing

Tags: excel, vba

Excel security warning, that macros has been disabled stop showing on the start of excel.

Only way I can allow it now is on ribbon "File" where is warning that some content has been disabled.

How can I get it back so it will show on the start of Excel? It stopped working couple weeks ago and it stopped for all people in the office. My private office works normaly. Both Excels are 365.

Comment: It sounds like your Office 365 administrator has changed the macros permissions for everyone. If is not completely disabled on your end, you can follow @Pawel's answer, but otherwise you would have to take this up with your Office 365 administrator. See more info [here](https://www.microsoft.com/security/blog/2016/03/22/new-feature-in-office-2016-can-block-macros-and-help-prevent-infection/).

Answer (score 0):

You can change this setting in File/Options/Trust Center/Trust Center Settings/Macro Settings -> Mark 'Disable all macros with notification'. Note that this setting might be locked by your system administrator.

[image]